# Create event on my GSuite Calendar and inviting attendees using Service Account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-developers-console

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Trying to invite someone to an event through a google service account.

***Step one - I went to the developer console and added a service account, got the key (stored in better.json in the code below), gave it Calendar API permissions, and it's got oath2 permissions:***

[image: snapshot of my credentials panel]

***Step two - I gave my service account 'GSuite Domain-wide Delegation'***

[image]

***Step three - On the GSuite side, I went logged in to my admin panel, found this little guy and made the proper updates.  I think? Scope? :***

[image: snapshot of my advanced security settings]

Last but not least, here's the code I'm running.

```
require 'googleauth'

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'

authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open('better.json'),
  scope: scope)

authorizer.fetch_access_token!

service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
service.authorization = authorizer

calendar_id = 'primary'



event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
  summary: 'douchin',
  location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  description: 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
    date_time: '2020-04-06T09:00:00-07:00',
    time_zone: 'America/New_York'
  ),
  end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
    date_time: '2020-04-06T10:00:00-07:00',
    time_zone: 'America/New_York'
  ),
  recurrence: [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  guestsCanModify: 'TRUE',
  attendees: [
    Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(
      email: 'brianthebiologist@gmail.com'
    )
  ],
  reminders: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event::Reminders.new(
    use_default: false,
    overrides: [
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(
        reminder_method: 'email',
        minutes: 24 * 60
      ),
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(
        reminder_method: 'popup',
        minutes: 10
      )
    ]
  )
)

result = service.insert_event('primary', event)

puts "Event created: #{result.html_link}"


response = service.list_events(calendar_id,
                               max_results: 10,
                               single_events: true,
                               order_by: 'startTime',
                               time_min: Time.now.iso8601)
puts 'Upcoming events:'
puts 'No upcoming events found' if response.items.empty?
response.items.each do |event|
  start = event.start.date || event.start.date_time
  puts "- #{event.summary} (#{event.html_link})"
end
```

I have two problems.

1) If I try to create an event ***with an attendee*** (this is what I'm really after), I get the error:  forbiddenForServiceAccounts: Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority. (Google::Apis::ClientError)

2)If I try to create an event ***WITHOUT any attendees***, it says it works, and stores the information in some magical calendar somewhere...but it does not show up in my GSuite calendar when I login to my admin account on Google.  So my auth worked..I think..It kicks back an event link, but when I try to go to it I get another error: "could not find requested event" on the google calendar ui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - figured this out.  I just needed to use Signet to produce a token instead of whatever I was using, example below where privatekey = my service accounts private key cred:

```
signing_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(privatekey.gsub("\\n", "\n"), 'notasecret')
authorizer = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  {
    signing_key: signing_key,
    token_credential_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    audience: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    issuer: ENV['service_account_email'],
    person: ENV['email_on_my_domain_i_want_to_impersonate'],
    scope: scope
  })

token = authorizer.fetch_access_token!
```

Hope this helps someone someday! upvote if it does.

Comment: This worked for me. The `authorizer.fetch_access_token!` took a while though (~30sec)